# Calculo antecesor de un nodo

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos

Lo primero explicaré el código para que las respuestas puedan ser precisas.

El antecesor de un nodo se define como la mínima diferencia  entre el nodo del que se desea calcular el antecesor y los demás nodos del árbol.

**Método lanzador calcularAntecesor:**

1) Compruebo que el objeto x que paso como parámetro, efectivamente, se encuentra en el árbol. 
  2) Una vez hecha la comprobación, llamo al método recursivo.

**Método calcularAntecesor:**

Primero se busca el nodo dentro del árbol. La búsqueda se fundamenta en los principios de los árboles ABB. Una vez encontrado se diferencian dos casos:

1) El nodo del que se va a calcular su antecesor no tiene subárbol izquierdo.           Dado que se trata de un árbol de búsqueda binario, el antecesor será el padre de ese nodo. (Método recuperar padre)

2) El nodo en cuestión tiene subárbol izquierdo. Luego, se calcula el elemento mayor del subárbol con nodo raíz, el nodo del que se va a calcular el antecesor.
(Método calcular mayor)

Ahora bien, me parece que el código en sí es un poco farragoso y poco eficiente (Dado las múltiples llamadas recursivas). ¿Alguna idea para mejorarlo?

```
 @Override
    public NodoABB calcularAntecesor(Object x) throws ElementoNoEncontrado
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        NodoABB res;
        String cadena = super.toStringInOrden();
        for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++)
            if(x.toString().compareTo(x.toString()) == 0)
                flag = true;
        if(flag == true)
        {
            res = calcularAntecesor(x, super.raiz);

        }
            else 
            throw new ElementoNoEncontrado("Elemento no encontrado");

        return res;
    }

    protected NodoABB calcularAntecesor(Object x, NodoABB actual)
        { 
            int res = x.toString().compareTo(actual.dato.toString());
            if(res > 0)
                actual = calcularAntecesor(x, actual.der);
            if(res < 0)
                actual = calcularAntecesor(x, actual.izq);
            if(res == 0)
            {
                if(actual.izq != null)
                {
                    return calcularMayor(actual, actual, actual);
                }
                else
                    try{
                        return recuperarPadre(actual, super.raiz);
                    }catch(ElementoNoEncontrado excp){System.out.println(excp.getMessage());}
            }
            return actual;

        }

        private NodoABB recuperarPadre(NodoABB resul, NodoABB actual ) throws ElementoNoEncontrado
        {   
            if(actual == null)
                throw new ElementoNoEncontrado("No está el elemento");
            if(actual.izq != null && actual.izq.dato.toString().compareTo(resul.dato.toString()) == 0)
                return actual;
            if(actual.der != null && actual.der.dato.toString().compareTo(resul.dato.toString()) == 0)
                return actual;
            if(actual.izq == null && actual.dato.toString().compareTo(resul.dato.toString()) == 0)
                return actual;
            if(actual.der == null && actual.dato.toString().compareTo(resul.dato.toString()) == 0)
                return actual;
            int res = actual.dato.toString().compareTo(resul.dato.toString());
            if(res < 0)
                return recuperarPadre(resul, actual.der);
            else
                return recuperarPadre(resul, actual.izq);
        }


        private NodoABB calcularMayor(NodoABB actual, NodoABB anterior, NodoABB raiz2)
        {
            NodoABB raizSub = raiz2;
            NodoABB min = actual;
            anterior = actual;
            if(actual.izq != null)
                min = calcularMayor(actual.izq, anterior, raizSub);
            if( Integer.parseInt(anterior.dato.toString()) < Integer.parseInt(actual.dato.toString()))
                min = actual;
            if(actual.der != null && actual.der.dato.toString().compareTo(raizSub.dato.toString()) < 0)
                min = calcularMayor(actual.der, anterior, raizSub);
            return min;
        }

    }
```

Comment: veo que los nodos tienen subnodos "der" e "izq". ¿tienen también nodo parent o padre, o no? Por otro lado, en el método público que pones la "flag" siempre te va a dar verdadero. ¿cuál es la condición para saber que un nodo es el que buscas? No me queda claro viendo el método público.

Comment: Si te refieres si tengo una referencia al nodo padre dentro de cada nodo, la respuesta es no, es por eso que utilizo el método recuperarPadre (En el caso que el nodo que vaya a calcular su antecesor, su referencia izquierda sea null, puesto que la menor de las diferencias con los demás nodos  sera la del nodo padre). En relación a lo del flag, si que puede ser false, ya que se puede dar el caso en el que el dato del nodo que recibe como parámetro (El método public) no esté en el árbol.

Comment: Hombre, hay cosas como if(x.toString().compareTo(x.toString()) == 0) que indican que el código es mejorable, pero para mejorarlo necesitaremos la clase y clases involucradas, no podemos conocer lo que no está especificado. ¿Podrías compartir la clase entera así como las clases que herede, si las hubiera? Sé que no hay herencia múltiple en Java, pero si hay una clase padre de una clase padre de tu clase, realmente me interesa a la hora de analizarla.